# Updating EditTexts on the fly

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to learn kotlin and I'm working on a simple conversion app where I have two edittexts. I would like for the calculation to happen automatically when I change the text. So if edittext2 is supposed to be 10 times larger than edittext1, I'd like edittext1 change to 10 if I enter 100 in edittext2 and if I change edittext2 to 50, edittext1 changes to 5, etc..

Currently I have a convert and clear button, but I would like to minimize the design and make it less cumbersome.

Comment: Please add your code so people can help you better.

Comment: There's not really much to add. I have two edittexts and a button in my layout, and in my kotlin file I have the mathematical formula for the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
    edittext2.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int,
                                   count: Int) {
            if (s != "") {
                val outPut=Integer.parseInt("get the value of editText1")+ Integer.parseInt("get the value of editText2")
                txtOutPut.text="$outPut"
            }

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int,
                                       after: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

        }
    })
```

Comment: That works. Thanks! I had played around with addTextChangedListener, but couldn't get it to work. I did change the if statement to (s.isNotEmpty() && edittext2.isFocused). Without the isFocused it wouldn't let me change the text. I guess since the two were at odds with each other.

Comment: let me know if more help required and upvote if it helped you.

Comment: (s.isNotEmpty() || edittext2.isFocused) why not to use or condition